# Access admin dashboardwordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, admin

When I try to access admin dashbord, an error is displayed. This error is: "Cannot redeclare use_block_editor_for_post()(previously declared in \wordpress\wp-includes\post.php:8067) in \wordpress\wp-admin\includes\post.php on line 2152".But the website is work correctly.
I use PHP 8.1 and Wordpress 6.0.3.

Any Help!!

Comment: Search all your code for `use_block_editor_for_post()`. The error is telling you that the function already exists somewhere and another function with the same name was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, backup all plugins through FTP to your computer.

Second, disabling all plugins or deleting them through FTP

Then check if the issue persists. If so, do the same for your theme. If the issue still persists, your installation might be corrupted.

Reinstalling plugins one by one, you will see which plugin caused the issue. Then you can investigate why. Probably an outdated version not compatible with the newest wp version and not maintained properly.